# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setNumberFormats on object SpreadsheetApp.Range - Existing answer doesn't help me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found the exact same question on here but I don't think the answer helps me.

I haven't ran this code for some weeks, it wasn't generating this error previously but now it is. I haven't changed anything, I literally just went to the data entry form I made and tried to use it. I can't see any typos, which was the answer to the existing question.

```
function addTrans(transInfoJSON){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  
  var transInfo = JSON.parse(transInfoJSON);
  
  ws.appendRow([generateID("TRANS"),
                transInfo.code,
                transInfo.cust_Id,
                transInfo.date,
                transInfo.description,
                transInfo.rate,
                transInfo.hours,
                transInfo.amntIn,
                transInfo.out]);
  
  var rngNewRow = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 4, 1, 7);
  var arrFormatsArray = [
    ["dd/mm/yyyy",,"£#,##0.00",,"£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00"]
    ];
  
  rngNewRow.setNumberFormats(arrFormatsArray);
}
```

The append works but when it gets to the last row I get the error.

Thanks to the new Google Apps Script editor it highlights things that match, so when I click on my variable name it highlights the name passed into the `setNumberFormats` method, even if I hadn't checked it letter for letter.

The array is the right size, the format strings follow the specification.  I'm just at a loss as to why the method is generating an error.

The `.amntIn` property of my object was originally called `.in`, which I now realise is a reserved word so I changed that, but it hasn't helped.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is due to the undefined value in `["dd/mm/yyyy",,"£#,##0.00",,"£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00"]`. In this answer, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the number format is overwritten by the value before `setNumberFormats` is used.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var rngNewRow = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 4, 1, 7);
var arrFormatsArray = [
  ["dd/mm/yyyy",,"£#,##0.00",,"£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00"]
  ];

rngNewRow.setNumberFormats(arrFormatsArray);
```

To:

```
var rngNewRow = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 4, 1, 7);
var defFormats = rngNewRow.getNumberFormats()[0];
var arrFormatsArray = [
  ["dd/mm/yyyy",defFormats[1],"£#,##0.00",defFormats[3],"£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00"]
];
rngNewRow.setNumberFormats(arrFormatsArray);
```

### Pattern 2:

When I saw your script, it seems that 2 number formats of `dd/mm/yyyy` and `£#,##0.00` are used. So in this pattern, `dd/mm/yyyy` and `£#,##0.00` are set by 2 `setNumberFormat()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var rngNewRow = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(), 4, 1, 7);
var arrFormatsArray = [
  ["dd/mm/yyyy",,"£#,##0.00",,"£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00","£#,##0.00"]
  ];

rngNewRow.setNumberFormats(arrFormatsArray);
```

To:

```
var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
ws.getRange(lastRow, 4).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
ws.getRangeList([ws.getRange(lastRow, 6, 1, 1).getA1Notation(), ws.getRange(lastRow, 8, 1, 3).getA1Notation()]).setNumberFormat("£#,##0.00");
```

### Note:

- Above modified script, Spreadsheet service is used. If you want to achieve your goal by one call, for example, I think that you can also achieve your goal using the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API. If you need it, please tell me.

### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setNumberFormat(String))

Comment: Thanks, these methods both worked.  Pattern 2 was very slightly faster on average than pattern 1 according to Google's execution log, which surprised me, so may stick with that.  I'm surprised this stopped working and the documentation hasn't changed to reflect that the formats array can't contain empty values.

Comment: @Martin Bannister Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.